# Problem finding the volume of this solid of revolution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solid-of-revolution

lest say we have the function $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3} = a^{2/3}$ and we want to Find the volume of the solid of revolution generated
when the area bounded by the given curves is revolved
about the x-axis hence:

$$y = (a^{2/3}-x^{2/3})^{3/2}$$

lets do the method of disk a tiny disk has volume:

$$dV= \pi (a^{2/3}-x^{2/3})^{3}dx$$

the volume of the total solid is then:

$$V = \int_0^a\pi (a^{2/3}-x^{2/3})^{3}dx$$

$$=\int_0^a \pi(a^2-3a^{4/3}x^{2/3}+3a^{2/3}x^{4/3}-x^2)dx$$

$$=a^2x-3a^{4/3}\frac{x^{5/3}}{5/3}+3\frac{a^{2/3}x^{7/3}}{7/3} - \frac{x^3}{3}$$

$$a^3-3\frac{a^{9/3}}{5/3}+3\frac{a^{9/3}}{7/3} - \frac{a^3}{3}$$

my problem is that I am not getting the correct form:
$$16\frac{\pi a^3}{105}$$

note: the volume is only in the first quadrant.

Comment: Careful: $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = a^{2/3}$ is not a function. Can you show how you expanded the cube?

Comment: Can you add more steps between $\int_0^a\pi (a^{2/3}-x^{2/3})^{3}dx$ and $\pi (a^2+a-\frac{a^3}{3})$?

Comment: ok I am editing

Comment: it is done......

Comment: $\pi(a^2-3a^{4/3}x^{2/3}+3a^{2/3}x^{4/3}-x^2)$ is from expanding the cube, and you still have to integrate that.

Comment: sorry a typo...

Comment: I did integrate before edit

Comment: Now is the correct form Ready

Comment: For one of the terms, integrating $$\int_0^a 3a^{4/3}x^{2/3}dx = 3a^{4/3}\cdot \left[\frac 35x^{5/3}\right]_0^a = \frac 95 a^{4/3}a^{5/3}$$

Comment:  sorry my brain was on low oxigen

Comment: Still I cant reach the correct form evaluating in a gives $a^3-\frac{a^{9/3}}{5/3}+3\frac{a^{10/3}}{7/3} - \frac{a^3}{3}$ != $ 16\frac{\pi a^3}{115}$

Comment: For debugging purpose like this, I would prefer that you keep more intermediate steps.

Comment: Like from [the answer from heropup below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4719714/89922) already gives an indefinite integration result. Then in your current version, where is the $3$ before $\frac{a^{9/3}}{5/3}$? How did you get an $a^{10/3}$ term?

Comment: heropup made a mistake in the first term $\int a^2 = a^2x$

Comment: @peterwhy I am editing my question

Comment: @peterwhy see updated question

Comment: Lastly, after extracting the common $a^3$, the problem becomes fraction addition and subtraction. Though [WolframAlpha agrees that the answer is *not* $16\cdot \frac{\pi a^3}{115}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=πIntegrate%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29Power%5Ba%2CDivide%5B2%2C3%5D%5D-Power%5Bx%2CDivide%5B2%2C3%5D%5D%5C%2841%29%2C3%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Ca%7D%5D).

Comment: @peterwhy another typo, instead of 115 is 105 is that the correct answer?

Comment: indeed thats the correct answer thanks @peterwhy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've differentiated when you needed to integrate:

$$
\int a^2 - 3a^{4/3} x^{2/3} + 3a^{2/3} x^{4/3} - x^2 \, dx
= a^2 x - 3a^{4/3} \frac{x^{\color{red}{5/3}}}{\color{red}{5/3}} + 3a^{2/3} \frac{x^{\color{red}{7/3}}}{\color{red}{7/3}} - \frac{x^3}{3} + C.$$